# Rails server won't start due to "uninitialized constant Devise::Mailer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

Few other solutions were suggested in several other posts and I did follow them like, requiring devise inside the application.rb file. I have also reinstalled the devise gem along with its dependencies. After trying for several hours, I can't figure out a solution and the stack trace keeps on showing me that **Devise::Mailer is an uninitialized constant with a Nameerror exception.**

I've also installed the devise invitable gem but it didn't solve the problem.
This actually started when I installed the gem facets and I'm using rails 5
Below you can have a look at the stack trace:

```
 usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Devise::Mailer (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:301:in `get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:320:in `mailer'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise_invitable-1.7.0/lib/devise_invitable/rails.rb:12:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I just got the same error after adding the facets gem. Only thing that changed is adding the gem, haven't even required anything from it. DId you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following:

```
rails g devise:install
```

then , `execute rails db:migrate`

Follow the steps on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise for more details

Make sure to restart the server after this

Comment: Forgot to mention that devise has been installed and the migration was executed, yet I am getting that stack-trace and error

Comment: Add the mailer settings in development.rb for sending mails

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have placed this code in the environment that you are using. So if you are using this in your development server you would need to go to `config` --> `development.rb` and insert this code. 

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`

For more information see the guide at: http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started